# Proguard is giving issue on release build in android?

Tags: android, file, google-api, storage, drive

I am building an android application. Where I have written a code for backup particular table data of database and pushing to google drive in app store in google drive.

It work perfectly on debugging mode but when I build a release APK it give me error. Which is null pointer on requesting "file.getId()".

Below is the code

```
private class MakeBackUp extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {
    private Exception mLastError = null;

    MakeBackUp(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
        Log.e("Error", "runnung4");
        HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        mService = new com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Builder(
                transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                .setApplicationName(getApplicationContext().getPackageName())
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * Background task to call Drive API.
     *
     * @param params no parameters needed for this task.
     */
    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.e("Error", "runnung3");
        try {
            return getDataFromApi();
        } catch (Exception e) {


            mLastError = e;
            Log.e("Error1", "errorPhase: " + mLastError);

            if (mLastError instanceof UserRecoverableAuthIOException) {
                Log.e("Error", "runnung4.5.3");                  
                startActivityForResult(
                        ((UserRecoverableAuthIOException) mLastError).getIntent(),
                        BackupAndRestoreMessage.REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);

            }
            cancel(true);
            onCancelled();
            return null;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Fetch a list of up to 10 file names and IDs.
     *
     * @return List of Strings describing files, or an empty list if no files
     * found.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private List<String> getDataFromApi() throws IOException {
        // Get a list of up to 10 files.
        List<String> fileInfo = new ArrayList<String>();
        FileList result = mService.files().list()
                .setPageSize(10)
                .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
                .execute();
        List<File> files = result.getFiles();
        if (files != null) {
            for (File file : files) {
                fileInfo.add(String.format("%s (%s)\n",
                        file.getName(), file.getId()));
            }
        }

        // upload db
        try {
            Log.e("Error", "runnung");
            File fileMetadata = new File();
            fileMetadata.setName("file_"+ System.currentTimeMillis() + ".json");
            fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList("appDataFolder"));
            Log.e("Error", "runnung0.1");
            java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File(getFilePath.BackupSMS(getApplicationContext()));
            Log.e("Error", "runnung0.2");
            FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("application/json", filePath);
            Log.e("File_Size", Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mediaContent.getLength() / 1024)) + "");
            Log.e("Error", "runnung0.3");
            File file = mService.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
                    .setFields("id")
                    .execute();
            Log.e("Error", "runnung0.4");
            try {
                Log.e("Error File ID: ", file.getId()); // System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());
                editor1.putInt("fileSize", Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mediaContent.getLength() / 1024))).apply();
                editor1.putString("fileDate", System.currentTimeMillis() + "").apply();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("Error0_", e.getMessage());
            }
            Log.e("Error", "runnung0.5");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Error0", e.getMessage());
        }


        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mProgress = new ProgressDialog(BackupAndRestoreMessage.this);
        mProgress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        mProgress.setCancelable(false);
        mProgress.show();
        mProgress.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#000000'>Creating local db dump</font>"));
        Log.e("Error", "runnung1");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> output) {
        Log.e("Error", "runnung2");
        if (pref.getString("fileDate", null) != null) {

            backupTym_size.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
            backupTym_size.startAnimation(out);

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    backupTym_size.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));

                    if (DateTimeDifferent(pref.getString("fileDate", null)) >= thisYearTotalDays()) {
                        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
                        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a");
                        Date date = new Date(Long.parseLong(pref.getString("fileDate", null)));
                        if (darkTheme) {
                            backupTym_size.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                        } else {
                            backupTym_size.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                        }

                        backupTym_size.setText("Google Drive: " + dateFormat.format(date) + "\nSize: " + pref.getInt("fileSize", 0) + " KB");

                    } else {
                        if (darkTheme) {
                            backupTym_size.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                        } else {
                            backupTym_size.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                        }

                        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
                        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM hh:mm a");
                        Date date = new Date(Long.parseLong(pref.getString("fileDate", null)));
                        backupTym_size.setText("Google Drive: " + dateFormat.format(date) + "\nSize: " + pref.getInt("fileSize", 0) + " KB");
                    }

                }
            }, 3000);

            snackbar("Backup completed successfully");
        }

        if (!BackupAndRestoreMessage.this.isFinishing()) {
            mProgress.dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        Log.e("Error", "runnung4.5.5");
        if (!BackupAndRestoreMessage.this.isFinishing()) { // or call isFinishing() if min sdk version < 17
            mProgress.dismiss();
        }
        if (mLastError != null) {
            Log.e("Error", "runnung4.5.1");
            mProgress.hide();
            if (mLastError instanceof GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException) {
                Log.e("Error", "runnung4.5.2");
                showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(
                        ((GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException) mLastError)
                                .getConnectionStatusCode());
                mProgress.hide();
            }
         {

            else {
                Log.e("Error", "runnung4.5.4");
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("Error", "runnung4.5.6");
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my proguard code

```
 release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFile 'proguard-android.txt'
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
```

Below is dependencies

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.6.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.2'
compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.3.0'
compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev102-1.23.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

Comment: have you generated a signed apk without proguard? if not, first attempt that, it will make sure you don't have any error for generating signned apk. Then try enabling proguard, also don't forget to add proguard rules

Comment: @DhavalPatel yes I have generated a signed apk without proguard. Its working.

Comment: @DhavalPatel When I set minifyEnabled false and shrinkResources false it will work.

Comment: add your dependencies with question

Comment: @RajeshKushvaha I have added dependencies in my question.

Comment: Add -keep class com.googlecode.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.googlecode.** -keep class com.google.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.** to proguard rules

Comment: I think there should be more dependencies pls add if any or try to add proguard rules by search with dependency name

Comment: @DhavalPatel I am getting error "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details"

Comment: @RajeshKushvaha The issue I am getting a in a code related to that code I have posted all dependency above

Comment: Yes i know, as i can see you have enabled `minifyEnabled true' so what compiler does it will obfuscation your code so when you run your apk it can't found some classes due to obfuscation thats why you need to add some proguard rules to avoid seems error

Comment: read this blog to understand proguard https://medium.com/tixdo-labs/obfuscating-and-optimizing-android-app-proguard-can-do-it-all-3d19c8ae9ec